# AlarmManager or JobScheduler compatible with all Android versions?

Tags: alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver, android-wake-lock, android-jobscheduler

I need some help deciding which classes to adopt in my app that has to fulfill these requirements:

- Firing of the alarms at exact times (down to the second)
- Can have multiple alarms in the system (triggering at different times).
- Should awaken the device if asleep and keep it awake until the user completes a defined task.
- Should run on as many Android versions as possible, at least from 4.0 and up (the fact that you can use an old phone to run this app is a plus).

I've coded a small demo with AlarmManager & BroadcastReceiver to get an understanding of how all of this works. I've studied the docs for AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver, WakefulBroadcastReceiver, and JobScheduler and even though I understand the differences, I don't know which one(s) will satisfy my requirements.

From the documentation, I get the impression that I might need to write multiple versions of my app to accommodate the different Android versions it will run on. This would be a nightmare!

Any suggestions on which classes to use? I would hate to go in one given direction only to later find out that I need to rewrite everything.

Thanks!

Comment: "Should awaken the device if asleep and keep it awake until the user completes a defined task." Never going to happen. Android goes very far out of their way to make sure that no app can keep the device awake when the user isn't touching it.

Comment: Have a look at `WorkManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple versions of your app, you just need multiple "scheduler" implementations, each with just a couple files, and all call the same app logic.

- Firing of alarms at exact times (down to the second)

Well, there's only one option that handles this. You need an AlarmManager.setExact. This is strongly discouraged, because it tends to waste battery.

- Can have multiple alarms in the system (triggering at different times).

Every option there handles that, as long as you give them different ids.

- Should awaken the device if asleep and keep it awake until the user completes a defined task.

Sounds like you need to have your alarm call Context.StartForegroundService, and leave that foreground service running until the user completes the task. Again, this is discouraged, because it wastes battery.

- Should run on as many Android versions as possible, at least from 4.0 and up (the fact that you can use an old phone to run this app is a plus).

AlarmManager and foreground services run on all versions of Android, though the call to start a foreground Service has changed slightly with Android O, the concept is identical.

---

While your app is doing something important that needs to execute RIGHT NOW, even if the screen is off, then you should grab a wakelock. A wakelock prevents the CPU from pausing itself, so that you can process what needs to immediately occur. If the code can wait until the screen is turned on, then please do not use a wake lock. JobService grabs a wakelock always, so JobService code does not need to grab a separate wakelock.  If you have no service running, including a JobService, then Android will randomly stop your app, even if you have a wakelock. So you always need a service of some sort, while doing any important work.

Comment: Hi MD, thanks again. Could you elaborate on multiple schedulers with files, I couldn't follow that one,

Comment: Also, it seems that a wakelock is enough - don't think I need foreground servicess

Comment: but JibScheduler seems to supersede wakelock?

Comment: @kxtronic: I can't elaborate on multiple schedulers with files, because those are 100% unrelated concepts, and I haven't the faintest idea what you're trying to ask of me.  Wakelocks are at least a related concept, I can discuss those.  You probably need a Foreground Service though, I added why.

Comment: Hi MD, let's go in steps. My first issue is that the alarm is inexact even on 4.0.3 which according to the docs should be exact at this OS level. Any ideas what I could do to get an exact alarm across as many Android versions as possible? (Please see code added above)

Comment: @kxtronic: No, Before API 19 (4.4), there was no way for an app to start itself at an exact time more accurately than AlarmManager.set or AlarmManager.setAlarmClock

Comment: Now another item that confuses me: Regarding battery I can live with the alarn waking up the phone and then staying awake for the normal screen timeout on the device (usually 1 min or so). What is the best way to achieve this? I read conflicting docs about using an activity vs a service. Could you perhaps shed some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: @kxtronic: You say "and then staying awake", but that's unclear. What should stay awake? The CPU? The Phone? Your service? Your Activity? Your process? Usually "awake" refers to the CPU, in which case you would use a WakeLock, which keeps the CPU awake. However, if you aren't busy processing like crazy, there's absolutely no reason to do such a thing.

Comment: Hi MD, The idea is that once the alarm triggers a) if the phone is awake the designated activity shows on the screen, b) if the phone is asleep it should wake up, and also show the designated activity on the screen. The user can act and click on OK. If the user does nothing then the phone should go to sleep after the preset time on the device. Thanks again for helping out !

Comment: In that case, you don't need anything to stay awake. Merely launch the Activity when the alarm goes off.

Comment: Hi MD, I was unplugged for a couple of days. You hit the nail on the head with that comment, I was also slowly getting there: I just need to launch the activity. Thanks!